How to Get Data on Keyword Search Frequency in Google Maps for Different Cities?
I'm working on a project where I need to analyze how often a specific keyword (e.g., "laundry") is searched on Google Maps in different cities. I want to gather data on the frequency of this keyword appearing in search results specifically for Google Maps, not general web search.
Here are the steps I've considered so far:

Google Trends: I tried using Google Trends, but it does not
differentiate between Google Maps searches and general web searches.
Google Ads Keyword Planner: This tool provides search volume data
for keywords by location, but again, it's not specific to Google
Maps.
Google Places API: While it offers detailed information about
places and facilitates search functions, it does not provide data on
how often a keyword is searched in Google Maps.
Google My Business Insights: This provides some insights into search queries for my own business listings, but it doesn't help with general keyword search frequency across multiple cities.

My Question:
Is there any way to obtain or estimate the frequency of a keyword being searched in Google Maps for different cities? Are there any APIs, third-party tools, or methods that can help with this specific requirement?
Any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Are you sure that the search entries in the services you listed above don't have a property to them that like indicate those searches were from google maps specifically? Or like the URL/trace, because you could just collect all this data and put it in a table, and just ignore/delete rows that have a column saying they come from Google maps or maps.google.com.
If that's the case, then perhaps you should contact Google by emailing one of their support emails (idk how it works) and asking them if they have data of keywords or frequency of keywords searched in google maps.
